# how do I check if a username is unique (php, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I'm working on log-in/register form for school and i've encountered a problem.

How do I give an error message if you use a username that already exists on the database (I've used the UNIQUE KEY for the usernames)

Thanks in advance for any answers :) have a nice day

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        // check if passwords match
        if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']) {
            include_once("connect.php");
            $username = $dbCon->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = ($_POST['password']); 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, password, activated) "
                    ."VALUES ('$username', '$password', '1')";

            // if registration succesful, send to user.php, if not, error message
            if ($dbCon->query($sql) === true) {
                header('Location: user.php');
                echo "Registration succesful, Welcome $username";
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "Could not register, please fill in both username and password";
            }
        } else { // if the passwords do not match
            echo "Lösenorden matchar inte!";
        }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Just do a `SELECT * ...` and then check with a `foreach` if the user who was inputed is the same as one in the array.

Comment: Who can make a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTableName WHERE Username = 'username'`, if 1 is return, the username exists.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: And what about: *Dont SAVE passwords as PLAIN text in the Database!!!*

Comment: Or look at the error code from the INSERT and if it is the duplicate entry error, give appropriate error message

Comment: PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: fyi @WasteD 's comment is sarcasm. Don't actually implement it.

Comment: @ThomasRollet it is not necessary to perform a select to check for the existence of the username. Relying on the unique index is enough, see RiggsFolly's comment.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I found a dupe target for this question

Comment: @Shadow Not the greatest answer but it will do

Comment: @Dimi Actually it wasn't xD it was just the first thing  which came in my head I didn't think of the `COUNT` variant ...